# Distance between two coordinates with CoreLocation

Tags: iphone, core-location

I need to calculate the distance (in meters and miles) between two coordinates given

How can I do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Returns the distance (in meters) from the receiver’s coordinate to the coordinate of the specified location.

```
// Deprecated in iOS 3.2 method
- (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(const CLLocation *)location

// Correct method
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

[CLLocation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/getDistanceFrom:)

Comment: Geting any other distance would be problematic without defining a path. If you define a path, you're asking for a path length, not the distance between two points.

Comment: CLLocation link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html

Comment: Downvoting since the method's now deprecated.

Comment: @Spanky This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations.

Answer (score 18):

The method in the previous answer has been [deprecated in iOS 3.2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/getDistanceFrom:).  The new method is the very similar

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

which also returns a distance in meters.  It's accounting for the curvature of the earth.

Answer (score 0):

swift 3
func distance(from location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance
Description 
Returns the distance (measured in meters) from the receiver’s location to the specified location.
This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth. The resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account specific altitude changes between the two locations.
Parameters
location
The other location.
Returns 
The distance (in meters) between the two locations.
SDKs    iOS 3.2+, macOS 10.6+, tvOS 9.0+, watchOS 2.0+
Declared In Core Location
More    Method Reference

e.g.

```
let distance = location.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: 
CLLocationDegrees(oldLocationLat), longitude: 
CLLocationDegrees(oldLocationLng)))
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3

```
func distance(from location: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance Description
```

Returns the distance (measured in meters)

e.g.

```
locations: [CLLocation]

let location: CLLocation = locations.last!

let distance = location.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(oldLocationLat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(oldLocationLng)))
```